# Parse nested JSON in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

How to parse nested Json object inside Javascript?

The PHP program that forms the Json string and return to client

```
$menu_items = array(
  "Account" => "account",
  "Send SMS" => "send-sms",
  "Remote Address Book" => "remote-address-book"
);

$arrLoginResponse = array (
  "success" => true,
  "url" => "someurl",
  "token" => "100",
  "menuitems" => $menu_items
);
$jsnLoginResponse = json_encode($arrLoginResponse);

return $jsnLoginResponse;
```

In the jQuery I have

```
var jsnObj = jQuery.parseJSON(loginResponse);
var username = jsnObj.url;  //this works fine and return the url string
var menuitems = jsnObj.menuitems; //this is returning as an object
```

I want to recieve menuitems as array and loop through the array and get the values.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hopefully you're echoing out that string, and not just returning it ?

Comment: `var menuitems = jsnObj.menuitems; //this is returning as an object` well, yeah, it is an object. what did you expect? it isn't an array, it's an object. you can still iterate over the keys in an object.

Comment: In Javascript, associative arrays are the same thing as objects.

Comment: Kevin B, I want to retrieve the menuitems as an array and not as object.  I can also change the PHP program if required.  What is the best way?

Comment: If you want to receive it as an array, use `array("account", "send-sms", "remote-address-book")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can loop over the elements of an object in jQuery

```
$.each(menuitems, function(key, value) {
    // Do something with key and value
}
```

Comment: Barmer, this works as expected.  Even though I receive it as an object and since my object contains similar type of data, I can look through the object and get the values from an object like an array.

Comment: Javascript objects can be accessed similarly to arrays in general. If you have a property in a variable, you can use `obj[prop]` to get the value of that property.